# Sinch SDK video calling Local View remains freezed to last call last captured frame

Tags: ios, iphone, video, swift3, sinch

I m having the issue that local view remained stucked till the opposite 
user gets the call and when the opposite user gets called the last frame 
captured from the last video call then only the local view comes into 
the movement else it remains freezeed until the user doesnt gets call.
Note: Works well when placing the video call for the first time
attaching the video link for better understanding :
https://youtu.be/e7M98AFraTE

Steps i have conducted and i m having the following issue

1) Placing the call to the random[any] user.

2) When call gets starts it starts rendering the local and remote view 
and when the call ends the last captured frame in the local view is 
getting stored

3) When placing the call again to the same user or any other user the 
last captured frame remains in the local view until 2-3 seconds till the 
opponent user doesnt gets the call signal and then local view gets in 
movement[The freezed image gets out of that view and shows the live 
video]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will make a change in the SDK to make sure the capturer is cleared upon a new call. This should resolve the issue where the last captured frame is displayed while waiting for the next call to connect.